# excel vba sort sheet numerically

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sort sheets in my excel file. I found [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=72) code which works. But the problem is that my sheet names are 1_abc, 2_adf, 3_dasf, 11_ad etc. This code puts 11_ad before 2_adf and 3_dasf. I would like to sort sheets based upon number before "_" (first underscore) in my sheet name. How could I do the same?

################################UPDATE1

I modified the code as below. But it is sorting in descending order :(. I want to sort in ascending order

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortWorksheets()

    Dim N As Integer
    Dim M As Integer
    Dim FirstWSToSort As Integer
    Dim LastWSToSort As Integer
    Dim SortDescending As Boolean

    SortDescending = False

    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count = 1 Then

         'Change the 1 to the worksheet you want sorted first
        FirstWSToSort = 1
        LastWSToSort = Worksheets.Count
    Else
        With ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
            For N = 2 To .Count
                If .Item(N - 1).Index <> .Item(N).Index - 1 Then
                    MsgBox "You cannot sort non-adjacent sheets"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next N
            FirstWSToSort = .Item(1).Index
            LastWSToSort = .Item(.Count).Index
        End With
    End If

    For M = FirstWSToSort To LastWSToSort
        For N = M To LastWSToSort
            If SortDescending = True Then
                If CLng(Split(Worksheets(N).Name, "_")(0)) > _
   CLng(Split(Worksheets(M).Name, "_")(0)) Then
                    Worksheets(N).Move Before:=Worksheets(M)
                End If
            Else
                If CLng(Split(Worksheets(N).Name, "_")(0)) > _
   CLng(Split(Worksheets(M).Name, "_")(0)) Then
                    Worksheets(N).Move Before:=Worksheets(M)
                End If
            End If
        Next N
    Next M

End Sub
```

Comment: Relabel your worksheets 01_abc, 02_adf, 03_dasf, 11_ad etc.

Comment: You're using the `>` comparison in both blocks - look again at the original code

Comment: thanks Tim. It is working now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
If UCase(Worksheets(N).Name) > UCase(Worksheets(M).Name) Then
```

you need something like this:

```
If CLng(Split(Worksheets(N).Name,"_")(0)) > _
   CLng(Split(Worksheets(M).Name,"_")(0)) Then
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it is giving problem in update1 above

Comment: You need one block with `>` and one with `<`

Comment: i have sheets like 01_Sheet2, 02_Sheet3, 1_Sheet1 and this vba code is putting 1_Sheet1 at the end. I would 1_Sheet1 to apper before 02_Sheet3 as '1' is < '02'. How should i modify this code?

Comment: That's quite different from your original question - You should post a new question for this

Comment: done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479146/excel-vba-sort-sheet-numerically-by-looking-at-first-few-characters