# excel vba sort sheet numerically by looking at first few characters

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I want to sort sheets in my excel file. My sheet names are 12_abc, 122_adf, 3_dasf, 11_ad etc. I would like to sort sheets based upon number before "*" (first underscore) in my sheet name. While doing the sorting the code should understand that 3 should appear before 134. The code needs to take text before "*" and convert it to number.

How could I do the same? This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380594/excel-vba-sort-sheet-numerically/43380689?noredirect=1#comment73985759_43380689). I am posting a new question based upon comments that I received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try...

```
Sub SortSheetTabsAscending()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
        If Split(Sheets(j).Name, "_")(0) + 0 > Split(Sheets(j + 1).Name, "_")(0) + 0 Then
            Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```